# flutter circular image view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Iam new to flutter and I want to achieve a circular image view like below. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This really  simle. Please use Stack and [CircleAvatar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html)

```
 Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('img/img1.png'), ///Your image here  from pubspec.yaml
            radius: 50,
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.8),//Chage this to position your dot
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
          )
        ]
      )
```